# How to create a trigger (or type of) in ms access 2003?

Tags: vba, events, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have purchased an application, it has `VB` and `MS ACCESS` 2003 used.application insert or update ms access on button click.I want to create a **trigger** or a **stored procedure** or an **event** on a table which insert a new row to another table if a primary table get updated or inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature (which Access calls "event-driven Data Macros") was added to the Access 2010 .accdb file format. It is not available in the earlier .mdb file format as used by Access 2003.